# PHP variable assignment in foreach loop - unknown behavior

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach

This has me completely stumped. I am using a Cakephp 3.9.6 application and tplaner/When library on PHP 7.4 to generate recurring events. Somewhere, the start and end dates are being set as the same date. Here is the section from my EventsController::add method:

```php
$data = $this->request->getData();
$copies = new When();

$copies->freq($data['frequency'])
    ->interval($data['interval'])
    ->wkst('MO');
if ($data['frequency'] == 'WEEKLY') {
    $copies->byday(implode(',', $data['days']));
}

if (!empty($data['count'])) {
    $copies->count($data['count']);
} else {
    $copies->until(new DateTime($data['last_date'] . " 23:59:59"));
}

$copies->startDate(new DateTime($event->start->toDateTimeString()))->generateOccurrences();
$newCopies = $copies->occurrences;
$interval = $event->start->diff($event->end);

foreach ($newCopies as $copy) {
    Log::debug($copy); //Shows the next date in the series calculated from start date
    if ($copy == $event->start) {
        continue; //First event already saved in rest of action, do not create another copy
    }
    $temp = $event->toArray(); //copy entity details to array
    $temp['start'] = $copy; //assign new start time
    $start = $copy; //thought maybe due to race condition? Copying to new object to modify end time
    $temp['end'] = $start->add($interval); //$interval calculated from original event data, added to new start time
    Log::debug($temp);

    $result = $this->Events->newEntity($temp); //return to new entity
    Log::debug($result);
    $events[] = $result; //add to array of entities for saveMany()
}
```

The problem I have is that the new start date in the array/entity are the same as the end date:

`Log::debug($copy)` outputs the correct new start date

`Log::debug($temp)` shows the array, but the start and end properties are the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do $start=$copy as they will be the same "object" with different references, you actually want to CLONE $copy so it is a separate object.  So when you alter one you do not touch the other

Comment: Alternatively, one could use `DateTimeImmutable` and then it would work as it is.

Comment: Is the When() class a DateTime derived class?

Comment: Yes, it is: `class When extends DateTime`
https://github.com/tplaner/When/blob/master/src/When.php. Also thanks, never had to use `clone` before.

Comment: Good point. It's derived from the mutable version. Therefore, my previous comment is invalid.